# Intergrating Proclipsing into Eclipse Project, screen won't appear

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I have a project that on it's own functions as I would like it to. It's a small game about the player (a blob) picking up randomly spawning items in an attempt to keep their "happiness" from hitting 0.

I originally wrote it in BlueJ, but I asked a friend who is more adept in programming about giving it graphics. He said that while the swing package would work, it would be better in Eclipse with Processing.

I set it up with him on my computer over Skype, moved all my files from BlueJ to Eclipse, and began working on making a class for the visuals to function it.

Here's the code (All variables and functions from the Map class are functioning):

```
public void setup()
{
    //int x = gameMap.getXScale()*5 + 5*(xSC+2);
    //int y = gameMap.getYScale()*5 + 5*(ySC+2) + 150;
    gameMap = new Map(MapTypes.treasureRoom(), BlobTypes.trBlob());
    xSC = gameMap.getXScale();
    ySC = gameMap.getYScale();
    sze = 100;
    spc = 5;

    int x = gameMap.getXScale()*5 + 5*(xSC+2);
    int y = gameMap.getYScale()*5 + 5*(ySC+2) + 150;
    size(x,y);
}

public void draw()
{
    int[] rgb = gameMap.getBlob().getRGBVal();
    int r = 204;
    int g = 102;
    int b = 0;
    Node[][] n = gameMap.getMapOfNodes();
    background(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < ySC; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < xSC; j++){
            if(n[j][i].getNodeType() == 0){
                r = 128;
                g = 128;
                b = 128;
            }else if(n[j][i].getNodeType() == 1){
                r = rgb[0];
                g = rgb[1];
                b = rgb[2];
            }else if(n[j][i].getNodeType() == 2){
                r = 204;
                g = 153;
                b = 255;
            }else if(n[j][i].getNodeType() == 3){
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
            }
            rectt(j*10+spc, i*10+spc, sze, sze, 5, r, g, b);
        }
    }

    fill(100);
    rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}

void rectt(float x, float y, float w, float h, float ra, int r, int b, int g)
{
    fill(r,b,g);
    rect(x, y, w, h, ra);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

It is inside a `Game()` class that `extends PApplet`. When I try running it (as an application), no screen shows up at all. What do I do?

EDIT: The `Node[][]` near the beginning of `draw()` is an array of each individual point on the Map that the player can be. Also, the `MapTypes` and `BlobTypes` objects are just a collection of methods for storing different `Map objects` and `Blob (the player) objects`.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't calling anything in your main method class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

I can't personally tell you what all you need to call from this class but it should be something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThisClass main = new ThisClass(parameters if any);

    main.setup();
    while(game is not over){
        main.draw();
        update other game logic
       }
}
```

As a note, one iteration of your while loop is equvilant to one frame. So everything you want to be accomplished per frame, must be placed in here.

Comment: It gives me an issue, stating "When not using the PDE, size() can only be used inside settings(). Remove the size() method from setup(), and add the following: public void settings() { size(100,250); }" as well as several other errors.